# How is Github Enterprise hosted?

Tags: github

How exactly does github enterprise (or similar services) allow you to install it and host on your own servers without being open source?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with GitHub Enterprise, but it appears it's just a OVF package (commonly used format for packaging an entire virtual machine) that you just import and go.. a full stack including the OS and all. It's not something you just install alongside other things like WordPress (or at least it doesn't appear to be.)

Comment: but couldn't you just open up the ovf?

Comment: Well, you import it in your VM software, start up the VM (just like turning on your computer), and it's all pretty much ready to go. For example, the package contains the entire operating system, my software, software depencies, databases, servers, etc. There is nothing keeping you from looking at my software unless I specifically take action to keep you from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, it's an [Open Virtualisation Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) image which you can run in VMWare, VirtualBox or IBM Power.  You can read more in the [GitHub Enterprise FAQ](https://enterprise.github.com/faq).

The Virtual Image runs a Linux OS and the GitHub software.  Most of the work has been done for you, it's pretty much plug and [pay](https://enterprise.github.com/pricing) (licence for 40 users runs at $10k/year last time I checked).

Answer (score 0):

GHE is available as appliance and you can import the downloaded ova file to vmware and can configure it from the GUI after installation